# Pinax: I can't login to django admin are, but i know the login details

Tags: django, django-admin, pinax

I'm using pinax basic app.

I know my admin area login details, and i can't login! i changed them and still cannot login. Why is that happening?

Comment: No idea. We can't see any logs or whats going on with your machine. Try creating another superuser: `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: @jdi didn't work!!!! can i delete every superuser that i created and start from scratch?

Comment: You can delete it from the `python manage.py shell` by importing the User model and doing a delete. Or you can delete it directly from the database tables using whatever method you want. But if creating a new superuser didnt work, then there is probably something completely different that is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "can't login" ? What happens exactly ?

Comment: it says `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive.`

Comment: @ilvar here's [my settings.py](http://pastebin.com/YBfxc1vQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your settings.py, I notice that you deleted `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`. Adding this auth backend to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` should help.

More info:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends